# iOS RGB Color parameters do not match with an external design software

Tags: ios, image, swift, uicolor

We are changing  view color using

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:1)
```

then applying

```
let rect:CGRect = CGRectMake ( 0, 0, aWidth , aHeight ) as CGRect
let viewImage: UIImage = createFrameImageSize(rect)
```

we create an image then we share this image.
When we open  this image with a design software and check color we see that RGB parameters are 251, 0, 0 instead of 255, 0, 0. Is there a solution to handle this.

Comment: How are you sharing the image?

Comment: @Jonathan the color you propose is, for all intents and purposes, black. I think that OP is trying to make red.

Comment: It could be a colour space issue. iOS uses the sRGB colour space by default - have you tried checking the colour space on your design software?

Comment: The result will depend on the color profile selected for your monitor

Comment: @RoboticCat Thanks for your comment. It seems that is the reason.  

iOS does not support ColorSync, so all assets should be provided in the native device color space: sRGB.